# Edit a table through query using its own data

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an excel table with two blank columns which I would like to fill using joins with two other MS access database tables. I want the excel table itself to be updated and I don't want to create another table as a query result for space constraints. Is it possible? Would having the two access tables as an ODBC database help? I want the user to be able to run the query and have correct results even if he copies the files on his desktop.

I currently have an access query that gives me a result but it takes the excel table as a linked table for input. Once the query is completed it throws the resulting table back in place of the original excel table, replacing it. The problem is that if the user copies the file to his desktop, the table in the copied file will not have a link to the access linked table, which will still reference the original file and give different results.

Please let me know if I need to elaborate my problem. I have attached a picture to represent my current method. I want to make the excel linked table to be an independent table that can be put straight inside a query (be it access of excel query) no matter what location the workbook is saved in.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Access controls the link location of the excel file so when you move the excel file, of course, Access doesn't know that.  You can code some VBA code in your Excel file to pull the data you want from the Access file and populate the two blank column.  This way, it doesn't matter where the Excel file is, you can always pull the data since the Access dbs doesn't move (Assuming user have correct access to the MS Access dbs).

Comment: I could do that, but is there a better way, something using databases on the server and querying through excel?

Comment: You can link to access-tables in excel (google "link access data in excel"). Then you can move the excel file wherever you want as long as the path to the access-file stays the same.